# Trying to determine tensor

Tags: tensors

> Consider $\ f \in A^2(\mathbb{R}^3) $ (Alternating Tensors). Let $\ v_1$ = (2,3,1) $\ v_2$=(2,-5,4) $\ v_3$=(6,1,6) $\ v_4$=(4,6,2). We are given that $\ f$($\ v_1$,$\ v_2$)= 3. Determine $\ f$($\ v_3$,$\ v_4$)

I feel that I should be figuring out what the tensor does on the basis elements but not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Express $v_3,v_4$ as linear combinations of $v_1,v_2$. Then use the fact that $f$ is an antisymmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Hi so I found that $$ \ v_3 = 2v_1+v_2 $$ and  $$\ v_4=2v_1$$ so I am looking for $$/  f(2v_1+v_2,2v_1)$$ Then, since $$\ f(v_1,v_2) = 3  f(v_2,v_1) = -3 \to\ f(v_2,2v_1)= -6  \to\ f((1/2)v_2, 2v_1)=-3 \to\ 2f((1/2)v_2+v_1, 2v_1) = f(2v_1+v_2,2v_1) = 2(f((1/2)v_2 $$

Comment: You're making this more complicated than necessary. From bilinearity, you've got $$f(2v_1+v_2,2v_1)=(2)(2)f(v_1,v_2)+(2)f(v_1,v_1).$$ But the value of the second term follows from the antisymmetry of $f(u,v)$, and the value of the first is given.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Latex and I have to enter the comment to see how it comes out, I'll just leave it. You seem to know what I am trying to do. Thanks